# error in rmoving duplicates from unsorted linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

QSN. Given an unsorted linked list of N nodes. The task is to remove duplicate elements from this unsorted Linked List. When a value appears in multiple nodes, the node which appeared first should be kept, all others duplicates are to be removed. I tried to write this code on my own but showing error i attached after this code.

```
    class Solution
        {public: Node * removeDuplicates( Node *head) 
            { Node *curr =  head;
             Node *temp = head->next;
                while(curr!=NULL)
                {
                    temp = curr->next;
                    while(temp!=NULL)
                    {
                        if(curr->data == temp->data)
                        {
                            curr->next = temp->next;
                            temp = curr->next;
                        }
                        else
                        temp = temp->next;
                    }
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
            return head;
            }
        };
```

It is  not running for some testcases given below:

For Input: 1

6

2 2 2 3 4 2

Your Output:
2

Expected Output:
2 3 4

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the output it produces. Also, consider stepping through the code with a debugger. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre] of ***your own*** attempt, and [edit] your question to show it together with a detailed description of the problem you have with it.

Comment: Also consider checking for NULL before accessing the memory and not after

Comment: Also stop using worhtless "competition" and "online judge" sites to learn programming or programming languages, that's not what they're for. Invest in books and classes.

Comment: also, name the variables properly, temp is such a very bad choice of var name, and makes it very difficult to read the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use **unorederd_set** to maintain the data and use **prev pointer** to store the reference of previous node. We will iterate over the linked list if the data is not in the set we will add it to set if it is stored then we will make the previous node to point to the next of current note this way we can remove duplicates.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Solution{
    public: Node * removeDuplicates( Node *head) {
            Node *curr =  head;
            Node *temp = head->next;
            /*while(curr!=NULL){
                temp = curr->next;
                while(temp!=NULL){
                    if(curr->data == temp->data){
                        curr->next = temp->next;
                        temp = curr->next;
                    }else temp = temp->next;
                }
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            return head;
            */
            Node *prev;
            unordered_set<int> us;//To Store unique data
            while (curr != NULL){
                if( us.find(curr->data) == us.end()){//if not found in the set
                    prev=curr;
                    us.insert(curr->data);// adding to the set                      
                    curr=curr->next;//point to next one
                    
                }else{//found earlier in the set
                    prev->next=curr->next;
                    curr=curr->next;

                }
            }
            return head;
        }
};
```

Complete program where to remove **duplicate nodes** without using set remember here we are using a **previous node** if data encountered is **duplicate** then we will make the **previous node** to point to the **next node** of **current node** this way we can **remove** the **current node**(the duplicate one).

### Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Node{
    public :
        Node * next;
        int data;
        Node(){
            next=NULL;
            data=0;
        }
        Node(int data){
            this->data=data;
            next=NULL;
        }
};
//class Solution{
//  public: 
//
//};

//Removes Duplicates using an ordered_set
Node * removeDuplicates( Node *head) {
    Node *curr =  head;
    Node *temp = head->next;
    /*while(curr!=NULL){
      temp = curr->next;
      while(temp!=NULL){
      if(curr->data == temp->data){
      curr->next = temp->next;
      temp = curr->next;
      }else temp = temp->next;
      }
      curr = curr->next;
      }
      return head;
      */
    Node *prev;
    unordered_set<int> us;//To Store unique data
    while (curr != NULL){
        if( us.find(curr->data) == us.end()){//if not found in the set
            prev=curr;
            us.insert(curr->data);// adding to the set                      
            curr=curr->next;//point to next one

        }else{//found earlier in the set
            prev->next=curr->next;
            curr=curr->next;

        }
    }
    return head;
}
//Removes duplicates with out using list 
//Here maintaining a prev node will do the trick
Node * deleteDuplicates(Node * head){
    Node * curr = head;
    //Iterating all over the linked nodes
    while ( curr != NULL ){
        Node * temp=curr->next;
        Node * prev = curr;
        while(temp != NULL){
            //if this data is already there in list
            if(temp->data == curr->data){
                prev->next=temp->next;
            }else{
                prev=temp;//notice our prev is temp when this data is not equal to curr->data
            }
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    return head;
}
//add a node at the end
void addNodeAtEnd(Node * head,int data){
    Node * temp=head;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
        temp=temp->next;
    temp->next=new Node(data);
}
//displays all nodes
void printAllNodes(Node * head){
    Node * temp=head;
    while (temp != NULL){
        cout<<temp->data<<" ";
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
int main(){
    Node * head=new Node(5);
    addNodeAtEnd(head,20);
    addNodeAtEnd(head,30);
    addNodeAtEnd(head,30);
    addNodeAtEnd(head,30);
    addNodeAtEnd(head,5);
    addNodeAtEnd(head,30);
    addNodeAtEnd(head,40);
    addNodeAtEnd(head,50);
    addNodeAtEnd(head,30);
    addNodeAtEnd(head,50);
    addNodeAtEnd(head,20);
    printAllNodes(head);
    //head=removeDuplicates(head);
    head=deleteDuplicates(head);
    //displaying all the nodes after removing duplicates
    printAllNodes(head);
    return 0;
}
```

### Output :

```
$ g++ Node.cpp && ./a.out
5 20 30 30 30 5 30 40 50 30 50 20 
5 20 30 40 50
```

Comment: Thanks dev, I understand the solution using unordered set . But I want to know where is fault in my code. Can't we solve it without using set?

Comment: @Tanvi trace your code take pen and paper and see what curr and temp are pointing to for the given input you will find